# PyTorch installation on hardware-constrained device

Tags: python, installation, pytorch, debian-based, lego-mindstorms-ev3

I want to install PyTorch on a Debian Linux-based operating system ([ev3dev](https://www.ev3dev.org/)).

System specification (Lego Mindstorms EV3):

- 64 MB RAM
- TI Sitara AM18080 (ARM926EJ-S core) @300 MHz
- Installed Python versions: Python 3.5.3, Python 3.9.4
- 32 GB SD-Card

The following installation command:

```
pip3 install torch==1.10.0+cpu
```

leads to the error: `Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement torch==1.10.0+cpu`

Now, my question is, if it is possible to install and run PyTorch on such a system. And if it is possible to install, is it possible to run with acceptable performance?

Thank, you for any hints.

Comment: You forgot the flag `-f https://download.pytorch.org/whl/cpu/torch_stable.html`

Comment: If installing a pre-compiled package doesn’t work, you can try installing pytorch from source. Actually I would suggest installing from source, because then pytorch will be optimized. For your hardware.

Comment: @psarka Thank you for the hint. Unfortunately, this doesn't help.

Comment: It has to at least fail differently :) Ar you sure your pip3 is referring to 3.9.4? Try to do it properly: `python3.9 -m venv venv` then `source venv/bin/activate` then `pip install torch=1.10.0+cpu -f https://download.pytorch.org/whl/cpu/torch_stable.html` (note `pip` and not `pip3`).